# Scraping a xml document (nested url-structure)

Tags: r, xml, web-scraping

I do have a problem concerning the scraping of information from a certain xml-document (http://www.bundestag.de/xml/mdb/index.xml).

```
<mdbUebersicht>
<dokumentInfo>
<dokumentURL/>
<dokumentStand/>
</dokumentInfo>
<deleteRestore>
<deleteFlag>0</deleteFlag>
<deleteDate>20131202170000</deleteDate>
</deleteRestore>
<mdbs>
<mdb fraktion="Die Linke">
<mdbID status="Aktiv">1627</mdbID>
<mdbName status="Aktiv">Aken, Jan van</mdbName>
<mdbBioURL>
http://www.bundestag.de/abgeordnete18/biografien/A/aken_jan/258124
</mdbBioURL>
<mdbInfoXMLURL>
http://www.bundestag.de/xml/mdb/biografien/A/aken_jan.xml
</mdbInfoXMLURL>
<mdbInfoXMLURLMitmischen>/biografien/A/aken_jan.xml</mdbInfoXMLURLMitmischen>
<mdbLand>Hamburg</mdbLand>
<mdbFotoURL>
http://www.bundestag.de/blueprint/servlet/image/240714/Hochformat__2x3/177/265/83abda4f387877a2b5eeedbfd81e8eba/Yc/aken_jan_gross.jpg
</mdbFotoURL>
<mdbFotoGrossURL>
http://www.bundestag.de/blueprint/servlet/image/240714/Hochformat__2x3/316/475/83abda4f387877a2b5eeedbfd81e8eba/Uq/aken_jan_gross.jpg
</mdbFotoGrossURL>
<mdbFotoLastChanged>24.10.2016</mdbFotoLastChanged>
<mdbFotoChangedDateTime>24.10.2016 12:17</mdbFotoChangedDateTime>
<lastChanged>30.09.2016</lastChanged>
<changedDateTime>30.09.2016 12:38</changedDateTime>
</mdb>
```

The document contains a lot of short biographical aspects of different persons. Among other things it contains urls to other xml documents which contains a more detailed biography.

I try the following to get the information:

First I try to get all URLs for the different sub-documents from the maindocument

```
mdb_url <- xml_text(xml_find_all(xmlDocu, "//mdbInfoXMLURL"))
```

Then I implemented a for-loop which download all xml in my directory

```
for (url in mdb_url) {
  download.file(url, destfile = basename(url))
}
```

Afterwards I want to received a list of the files...

```
files <- list.files(pattern = ".xml")
```

... to get a specific node of every xml doc:

```
Bio1 <- files[1]

xmlfile <- read_xml(Bio1)

mdb_ausschuss1 <- xml_text(xml_find_all(xmlfile, "//gremiumName"))
```

Now I have the problem how I can do it for all xml files in the list? I haven't been able to write a functional loop or script for that task...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(xml2)
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(tools)
library(tidyverse)
```

Get the URL list from the main site XML

```
URL <- "http://www.bundestag.de/xml/mdb/index.xml"
doc <- read_xml(URL)
xml_find_all(doc, "//mdbInfoXMLURL") %>% xml_text() -> mdb_urls
```

Create a place to store them:

```
dir.create("docs")
```

Write them to disk (I’m only grabbing 10 of them since I don’t need the data, you do :-)

Note that `write_disk()` will not overwrite the path unless told to, so this is a great way to do poor-man’s caching. If you place this in a reproducible script, you'll have to try/catch wrap it.

```
walk(mdb_urls[1:10], ~GET(., write_disk(file.path("docs", basename(.)))))
```

Get the file list:

```
fils <- list.files("docs", pattern=".*.xml", full.names=TRUE)
```

Turn it into a data frame:

```
pb <- progress_estimated(length(fils)) # use a progress bar
map_df(fils, function(x) {

  pb$tick()$print() # increment the progress bar

  gremium_doc <- read_xml(x) # read in the file

  # find all the `gremiumName`s. If there are none, make the value `NA`
  xml_find_all(gremium_doc, "//gremiumName") %>% xml_text() -> g_names
  if (length(g_names) == 0) g_names <- NA_character_

  # make a tidy data frame
  data_frame(gremium=file_path_sans_ext(basename(x)), name=g_names)

}) -> df
```

Prove it works

```
glimpse(df)
## Observations: 33
## Variables: 2
## $ gremium <chr> "aken_jan", "aken_jan", "aken_jan", "aken_jan", "alban...
## $ name    <chr> "Auswärtiger Ausschuss", "Gremium nach § 23c Absatz 8 ...
```

Comment: Maybe you could help me a last time: How could I turn the data-structure easy from long to wide in that case? In that sense that for every new gremium there is a new column with the attribute ("Auswärtiger Ausschuss", "Wirtschafts Ausschuss" etc.) "true" or "not". I tried the resphape command but I don't get there.

Comment: totally separate question (SO rules/guidelines suggest that shld be a new q)