# Turn unique values into new columns and check for all other values

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, dcast

Thanks to @hrbrmstr I got a real good solution for the "[Scraping a xml document (nested url-structure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41678144/scraping-a-xml-document-nested-url-structure)" problem.

But as a result from that insight, it emerged another problem:

Now I have got the following data-structure...

```
 $Vorname   : chr  "Jan" "Jan" "Jan" "Jan" ...
 $ Nachname  : chr  "Aken" "Aken" "Aken" "Aken" ...
 $ ID        : chr  "1627" "1627" "1627" "1627" ...
 $ Fraktion  : chr  "Die Linke" "Die Linke" "Die Linke" "Die Linke" ...
 $ Reli      : chr  "" "" "" "" ...
 $ Geschlecht: chr  "Männlich" "Männlich" "Männlich" "Männlich" ...
 $ Auss_ord  : chr  "Auswärtiger Ausschuss" "Gremium nach § 23c Absatz 8 des Zollfahndungsdienstgesetzes" "Verteidigungsausschuss" "Unterausschuss Abrüstung, Rüstungskontrolle und Nichtverbreitung" ...
```

The only variable which actually variegate is "Auss_ord" which contains as value the different commission for MPs.

Now, what I want to achive is to switch from the current long version to a wide version of the dataframe.

For every unique value (certain text string) in "Auss_ord" there should be a new column and also be checked if it is "True" weather a another object has got same values.

So that...

```
     Vorname   Nachname    ID  Fraktion               Reli Geschlecht                                                         Auss_ord
     <chr>      <chr> <chr>     <chr>              <chr>      <chr>                                                            <chr>
1      Jan       Aken  1627 Die Linke                      Männlich                                            Auswärtiger Ausschuss
2      Jan       Aken  1627 Die Linke                      Männlich      Gremium nach § 23c Absatz 8 des Zollfahndungsdienstgesetzes
3      Jan       Aken  1627 Die Linke                      Männlich                                           Verteidigungsausschuss
4      Jan       Aken  1627 Die Linke                      Männlich Unterausschuss Abrüstung, Rüstungskontrolle und Nichtverbreitung
5  Stephan     Albani  1769   CDU/CSU                      Männlich    Ausschuss für Bildung, Forschung und Technikfolgenabschätzung
6  Stephan     Albani  1769   CDU/CSU                      Männlich                                         Ausschuss für Gesundheit
7   Katrin Albsteiger  1770   CDU/CSU römisch-katholisch   Weiblich                                                 Schriftführer/in
8   Katrin Albsteiger  1770   CDU/CSU römisch-katholisch   Weiblich         Ausschuss für die Angelegenheiten der Europäischen Union
```

...should be turned into...

[Example Dataframe (wide version)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISVF3.png)

I tried reshape operations like

```
d1 <- dcast(df, Vorname ~ Nachname ~ ID ~ Fraktion ~ Reli, value.var="ausord")
```

or

```
d2 <- reshape(df, idvar = "ID", timevar = "Auss_ord", direction = "wide")
```

...but I do not get any proper results, besides of the (for me) really tricky implementation of checking the uniqueness of a value

Comment: Here is [how to make a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5965451#5965451), a data frame would be better than the output of `str`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
dcast(df,Vorname+Nachname+ID+Fraktion+Reli+Geschlecht~Auss_ord,length)
```

`length` will allow the resulting dataframe to be filled with 0/1 for the columns generated with "Auss_ord"

Answer (score 0):

## Recreate data

```
politik <- read.table(text="Vorname   Nachname    ID  Fraktion  Reli Geschlecht Auss_ord
      Jan       Aken  1627 'Die Linke'         NA             Männlich                                            'Auswärtiger Ausschuss'
      Jan       Aken  1627 'Die Linke'        NA              Männlich      'Gremium nach § 23c Absatz 8 des Zollfahndungsdienstgesetzes'
        Stephan     Albani  1769   'CDU/CSU'           NA           Männlich    'Ausschuss für Bildung, Forschung und Technikfolgenabschätzung'",
header = TRUE)
```

## Answer using tidyr spread

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
politik %>% 
    mutate(present = TRUE) %>% 
    spread(Auss_ord, present)

  Vorname Nachname   ID  Fraktion Reli Geschlecht
1     Jan     Aken 1627 Die Linke   NA   Männlich
2 Stephan   Albani 1769   CDU/CSU   NA   Männlich
  Ausschuss für Bildung, Forschung und Technikfolgenabschätzung
1                                                            NA
2                                                          TRUE
  Auswärtiger Ausschuss
1                  TRUE
2                    NA
  Gremium nach § 23c Absatz 8 des Zollfahndungsdienstgesetzes
1                                                        TRUE
2                                                          NA
```

Be aware that your column names will be very hard to manipulate now. It's probably better to rename `Auss_ord` with some short acronym before the spread.